# how to call controller function on button click when my button is placed in different controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to AngularJS and making a single page application. Please see the attached screen shot I have a dropdown in which there is an apply button and on click of this button I want to call functions that are written in different controller. I have multiple dropdowns on a shell page I am attaching a screen shot of TimeLine dropdown for understanding. There are basically three dropdowns and they are same for every Tab that is why I've placed them in shell page. For example, there is one dropdown that is populating all clients name from database and have checkboxes so when user select multiple checkboxes and click on Apply button the view under these dropdown should be refreshed with new data.

[image]

**// This controller function is used to get data from database and fill the dropdown.**

```
 app.controller("FillDropDownController",function($scope,GetService,$rootScope){

    $rootScope.loading = true;
        // Calling Serivce Method here to get the data and fill dropdown
        $scope.GetDropDownValues = GetService.GetAll("CommonApi", "GetDropDownValues").then(function (d) {
            $scope.GetDropDowns = d;
            $rootScope.loading = false;
        });



// Here goes the function for ng-click = GetSelectedPractices() which gets the selected clients

$scope.GetSelectedPractices = function () { 
        $scope.selectedPractices = []; 
        angular.forEach($rootScope.PracticesList, function (d) { 
            if (d.selected == true) { 
                $scope.selectedClients.push(d.CLIENTNAME); 
            } 
        });  

        $scope.spanValues = $scope.selectedClients; 

    // I am stuck here that how to call controller functions for specific view

    }

    });
```

Here are two different controller functions (both are updating same view) that are fetching data from database and populate a table or draw a chart based on data. All these controller functions call a generic service to get the data. My problem is that my Apply Button dropdown is placed in shell page becuase if you see image no. 2 there are tabs on the page and this "Timeline" dropdown is same for all Tabs (On click of every tab there is a view loaded and its functions called and display table or draw charts on view).

```
app.controller("GetChargesController", function ($scope, GetService, $rootScope) {
    $scope.Title = "Charges Details List";
    $rootScope.loading = true;
    // Calling Serivce Method here to get the data
    $scope.GetChargesDetails = GetService.GetAll("CommonApi", "GetChargesDetails").then(function (d) {
        $scope.ChargesDetails = d;
        $rootScope.loading = false;
    });


     });

    app.controller("GetPaymentsController", function ($scope, GetService, $rootScope) {
    $scope.Title = "Payments Details List";
    $rootScope.loading = true;
    // Calling Serivce Method here to get the data
    $scope.GetPaymentsDetails = GetService.GetAll("CommonApi", "GetPaymentsDetails").then(function (d) {
        $scope.PaymentsDetails = d;               
        $rootScope.loading = false;
    });


     });
```

Comment: use emit/broadcast events for communication between controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="sample1Controller">
   <input type="button" value="Controller1" ng-click="sample1()"/>   
</div>
<div ng-controller="sample2Controller">  
</div>
</body>
<script>
var app=angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("sample1Controller",["$scope",'$rootScope',function($scope,$rootScope){
$scope.sample1=function(){
$rootScope.$broadcast('message');
}
}]);

app.controller("sample2Controller",["$scope",'$rootScope',function($scope,$rootScope){
$scope.sample2=function(){
console.log('called on click on sample1 button from controller1');
}

$scope.$on('message',function(){ $scope.sample2();});

}]);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine first time on loading page but if i call sample2controller function again or more than 2 times, in same view/html on click of button. It shows me error in console that $scope.sample1 is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `controller as vm` technique this (in theory) gives you access to the controller in all the child scopes with the name you give to it [here](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) is a post about this technique.

Comment: I recommend you not to make questions this large sometimes the people just past away them xD

Comment: Last time I've written small question and people were saying that question is very unclear to them and they down voted me :-( so I have tried to explain everything and share the code as well where  I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

from you shell page controller, broadcast the event whenever the filter is applied.

```
  $rootScope.$broadcast('UPDATE-GRAPH');
```

In your different tabs controller receive the broadcasted event and perform action  based on that.

```
 $rootScope.$on('UPDATE-GRAPH', function() {

       // call update function of your controller from here

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can directly extend your current controller with base controller so that it will access all function of it.

```
app.controller("BaseController",function($scope){
  // all functions you willing to call
});

app.controller("ExistingController",function($scope){
  // inherit base controller, using this even though your functions are in base   // controller it will get called
   $controller('BaseController', {$scope: $scope});
});
```